# "Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type never" in the parameter of the function call to get a value from an object key

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I need to render a list of products from the data stored in an object with a react router v6. I typed the object and created the typed function to get the value of a key following what is taught in [this github answer](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35859#issuecomment-663210925). This eliminated the previous error of ***Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' ts(2345)***, but a new error appeared: ***Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type ' never' ts(2345)***, which is pointed to the slug parameter of the getKeyValue call in the constant in the line `const shoe = getKeyValue(slug)(shoes);`.

```
const shoes: { [key: string]: { name: string; img: string } } = {
  'air-jordan-3-valor-blue': {
    name: 'VALOUR BLUE',
    img: 'https://secure-images.nike.com/is/image/DotCom/CT8532_104_A_PREM?$SNKRS_COVER_WD$&align=0,1',
  },
  'jordan-mars-270-london': {
    name: 'JORDAN MARS 270 LONDON',
    img: 'https://secure-images.nike.com/is/image/DotCom/CV3042_001_A_PREM?$SNKRS_COVER_WD$&align=0,1',
  },
  'air-jordan-1-zoom-racer-blue': {
    name: 'RACER BLUE',
    img: 'https://secure-images.nike.com/is/image/DotCom/CK6637_104_A_PREM?$SNKRS_COVER_WD$&align=0,1',
  },
};

const getKeyValue =
  <T extends object, U extends keyof T>(key: U) =>
  (obj: T): T[U] =>
    obj[key];

function LaunchIndex() {
  return (
    <ul>
      {Object.entries(shoes).map(([slug, { name, img }]) => (
        <li key={slug}>
          <Link to={`/launch/products/${slug}`}>
            <h2>{name}</h2>
            <img src={img} alt={name} />
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

function LaunchShoe() {
  const { slug } = useParams();
  const shoe = getKeyValue(slug)(shoes); // error here

  if (!shoe) {
    return <h2>Not found!</h2>;
  }

  const { name, img } = shoe;

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{name}</h2>
      <img src={img} alt={name} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

To resolve this error I followed what is in [this github answer](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31663#issuecomment-518854171), I changed the line to `const shoe = getKeyValue(slug as never)(shoes);`. So it worked, the application worked as expected, but I can't understand what's happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of `getKeyValue` is different from the Github post you linked. Here's the linked version:

```js
const getKeyValue = <T extends object, U extends keyof T>(obj: T) => (key: U) =>
  obj[key];
```

and here's your version:

```js
const getKeyValue = <T extends object, U extends keyof T>(key: U) => (obj: T): T[U] =>
  obj[key];
```

The problem is that you reversed the arguments. When you pass in the key parameter first, Typescript checks the constraint `U extends keyof T` and has no idea what to do because it has no idea what `T` is... the object hasn't been passed in yet! The result is the error message you saw.

If you reverse the arguments to match the implementation from the Github post, your code should work correctly.

Comment: Perfect, it worked correctly according to your explanation, but I didn't understand exactly why the order influences since the constraints are implemented within the same generic and the object's key call is done only at the end of the function, that is, regardless of the In order of typing T and U, they will already be typed when the index is assigned to the square brackets...

Comment: But Typescript doesn't type lazily... when you call `getKeyValue("someKey")`, the type-checker needs to know at compile-time if that's a valid argument. It can't say "well, I'll suspend judgement until the result gets called with an object." It needs to make a determination immediately, and it doesn't have enough information to do so. (If `getKeyValue` was a function with 2 parameters instead of a curried function, then the order of parameters wouldn't matter because both would be available at the same "time".)